# How to use the specific font in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to use my own specific font in my jasper reports.I am using the jasper reports-4.5.0.If i use the Helvetica as the font name in my jrxml file then i am getting the exception as Font not available to the JVM.How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can install TrueType fonts as follows in [iReport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport/iReport-4.6.0/)

Goto <kbd>Tools</kbd>**~>**<kbd>Options</kbd>**~>**<kbd>Reports</kbd>**~>**<kbd>Fonts</kbd>**~>**<kbd>Install Font</kbd>

Then follow the wizard from there.